# How to make some unit-tests for a purchase order

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm making an app that can let the user purchase, delete and change order, with the products comming from an already made database. But I have some problem in how to make the 3 most importants unit test, so I would like to receive some help please.

Here are the functions that I want to make a test from:

```
    public int addOrder(int ordernum, int idcustomer, int idproduct, int quantity, int shippingcost, Date salesDate, Date shippingDate, String company) throws SQLException {
    int result = 0;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO PURCHASE_ORDER VALUES=(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
    try (Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setInt(1, ordernum);
        stmt.setInt(2, idcustomer);
        stmt.setInt(3, idproduct);
        stmt.setInt(4, quantity);
        stmt.setInt(5, shippingcost);
        stmt.setDate(6, (java.sql.Date) salesDate);
        stmt.setDate(7, (java.sql.Date) shippingDate);
        stmt.setString(8, company);
        result = stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    return result;
}

public int deleteOrder(int OrderNum) throws SQLException {
    int result = 0;
    String sql = "DELETE FROM PURCHASE_ORDER WHERE ORDER_NUM = ?";
    try (Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setInt(1, OrderNum);
        result = stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    return result;
}

public int changeOrder(int Qte, int ordernum) throws SQLException {
    int result=0;
    String sql = "UPDATE PURCHASE_ORDER SET QUANTITY = ? WHERE ORDER_NUM=?";
    try (Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setInt(1, Qte);
        stmt.setInt(2, ordernum);
        result=stmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Well, basically I don't know where to begin in order to make these tests ...

Thanks in advance to anybody who would take the time to help me :D.

Comment: This isn’t a code-providing platform, try by yourself and ask for help with your best not working attempt. Furthermore, this seems to be part of a class, but nobody knows, how this class looks like.

Answer (score 0):

We have several ways to test the database.
You could have a dummy database that you would establish a connection before each test. Then execute your methods and at the end you check what's in the DB (in case inserts, checks if the entry is there).

If you are using Spring there is an easy way to do the testing with H2 (in memory DB). Ex: [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-test-in-memory-database)

If you are using Java without Spring, you can take a look in the [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/intro.html). Also this [tutorial](https://javaranch.com/journal/2003/12/UnitTestingDatabaseCode.html) will help you without requiring any additional plugin.

There is other frameworks that can help with Automated testing. For instance, [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) it's a Feature testing framework that can help test the whole flow and allows you to do checks in the DB during to check ehther the E2E flow is correct.

Note that, everything depends where you are running your testing. If it's just locally, then all the tools I mentioned will be easy to use. If is in a external server with Jenkins (or any other tool), it might require additional configuration